# Git clean -x option

Tags: git

In git-clean [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean), it says:

> -x
>
> Don’t use **the standard ignore rules** (see gitignore[5]), but still use the ignore rules given with -e options from the command line. This allows removing all untracked files, including build products. This can be used (possibly in conjunction with git restore or git reset) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.

While the output of `git clean -h` says:

```
...
-x                    remove ignored files, too
...
```

Aren't they contradictory? In my understanding, **the standard ignore rules** is rules from file `.gitignre` and `.git/info/exclude`, etc. According to the documentation, ignored files defined in file `.gitignore` shouldn't be cleaned by `git clean -fdx`, but in fact they are.

Comment: I think `don't use the standard ignore rules` means to act as if the ignore rules don't exist.

Comment: You forgot to mention the opening paragraph: "Normally, only files unknown to Git are removed, but if the -x option is specified, ignored files are also removed." I think that clarifies. I agree that it's very confusingly written. But it makes sense if you allow that "don't use" can mean "don't ignore".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not.  When it says, "don't use the standard ignore rules", it means, "don't ignore (i.e., don't prevent the removal of) files that match the standard ignore rules; treat them as any other untracked files."

Normally files that are ignored are preserved with `git clean -df`, but with `-x`, these files are not ignored because the standard ignore patterns are not considered, so the files are considered untracked and hence removed.

You are correct about what the standard ignore rules comprise.